# Excel Cell Currency Picker

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, microsoft-excel-365, dropdownlist

I want to show the currency symbol (as format not text or concat prefix) in a cell which is set as a defaulted **"AUD"** currency so it'll look like `AUD   1,450,000.00` but have that same cell also have a drop-down option to change it's format to other currencies. I understand one could simply format that cell and change the currency symbol but I'm looking for a neat option to have it all available in a drop-down for the technically challenged.

**End goal:** User enters a number, it shows as `AUD   xxx.xx` as default. If that number should be USD, they simply enter the number as usual then hit the drop-down and select USD which changes it to `USD   xxx.xx`.

This is more for a dash-boarding project. I could have just put the currency in one column and the number in the next column but that's not my aim here as I don't need these numbers for summing/analytics/formula working.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*I would you like to suggest the most easiest way,, the **Conditional Formatting method**, to change the currency symbol, based on the Drop Down.*

**Situation 1:**

*Currency selected is Rs.*

[image]

**How it works:**

1. Create Drop Down in cell M18, and add the required Currency as Text
   (Check Screen Shot).
2. Select required range.
3. Reach to `Conditional Format`, then `New Rule`.

[image]

4. Enter formula `=$M$18= "Rs".
5. Hit Format and select the related Currency from the list.

[image]

6. Finish with Ok.

**N.B.**

*Repeat step 2 to 6 for other Currencies.*

**Situation 2:**

*Currency selected is USD.*

[image]

*Another method is VBA Macro,, if you are comfortable with it, replay through comments.*

*Adjust cell references, and currency for Drop down as needed.*

Answer (score 0):

it does work, but when we copy paste the data somewhere else, it takes the currency of the destination .
so only option we have is to paste the data in JPG format.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1167597)